# Descargar BD en varios Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, cakephp, phpexcel

es que tengo un sitio que descarga las bd en un archivo de excel pero la cosa es que ya llego a tantos datos que el archivo de excel llega dañado, por lo cual se me ocurrió que podia solo subir digamos que de a mil datos y que cuando sea el dato mil uno lo guarde en otro archivo de excel, no se si eso se pueda.

este es mi código

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once "PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php";


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "");
mysqli_select_db($link, "");
$tildes = $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf16'"); //Para que se muestren las tildes correctamente
// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");
$result0 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM quote_new_users ORDER BY id DESC");//que carro cotizo
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM workshop_users ORDER BY id DESC");
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM soat_users ORDER BY id DESC");
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM democar_users ORDER BY id DESC");
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM contact_users ORDER BY id DESC");
$result5 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM use_users ORDER BY id DESC");
$result6 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM chevy_users ORDER BY id DESC");
$result7 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM spares_users ORDER BY id DESC");

//$result12 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM quote_new_users ORDER BY id DESC");
//$result13 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM quote_new_users ORDER BY id DESC");

$i=5;
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result0)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
// $titulosColumnas = array('Codigo', 'Nombre', 'Correo', 'Telefono', 'Fecha de creacion');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Correo')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono ')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
 // Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Cotizador');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'E'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);







$i=5;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['plate'])
            ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $fila['model'])
            ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Correo')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Placa')
            ->setCellValue('F3', 'Modelo')
            ->setCellValue('G3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Taller');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'G'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(1)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);





$i=5;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['plate'])
            ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Correo')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Placa')
            ->setCellValue('F3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Soat');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'F'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(2)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);






$i=5;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(3)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(3)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Codigo - Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Correo')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Demos');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'E'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(3)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(3)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(3);







$i=5;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(4)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(4)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Correo')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Contacto');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'E'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(4)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(4)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(4);





$i=5;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(5)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(5)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Email')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Usados');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'E'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(5)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(5)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(5);





$i=5;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(6)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(6)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Correo')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('ChevyPlan');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'D'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(6)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(6)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(6);







$i=5;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result7)){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(7)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $fila['id'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila['name'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila['email'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila['tel'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila['date_created'])
            ;
    $i++;
}
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(7)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'USUARIOS REGISTRADOS')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Codigo')
            ->setCellValue('B3', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Correo')
            ->setCellValue('D3', 'Telefono')
            ->setCellValue('E3', 'Fecha de creacion')
            ;
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Repuestos');
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'D'; $i++){
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(7)->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
            }
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(7)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(7);













$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Autolarte.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Este es el error que sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es por memoria ya que cuando quito algunas de las tablas ya si lo baja bn.

En cakephp me dijeron que existia algo que lo hacia pero en mysql puro no se como hacerlo.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator');

    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
            'Post.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es utilizar `limit` en las sentencias SQL:

`SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT OFFSET, COUNT;`

Donde `OFFSET` es a partir de que fila obtendrás los datos y `COUNT` es cuantas filas obtendrás.

Por ejemplo, si haces esta consulta en este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f0b72/1):

`SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 2, 1;`

Te dará como resultado el tercer elemento de la tabla, pues como `OFFSET` tiene 2, es decir, omitirá las primeras 2 filas y como `COUNT` tiene 1, te dará únicamente una fila.

Así que, si quieres saltar de 1000 en 1000 puedes hacer algo cómo esto:

`SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 1000;`

`SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 1000, 1000;`

`SELECT * FROM DATA LIMIT 2000, 1000;`

E ir guardando cada uno de los 1000 datos en un excel distinto con un `while`.

Comment: Si, eso lo implemente ayer, lo que no se es que me baje varios archivos de excel

Comment: Sólo puedes enviar un archivo en la respuesta de HTTP, te tocaría hacer un zip con todos los excel. Mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754359/7420363)